# Unsure How To Interpret the MongoDB node.js' Driver Callback Arguments For collection.insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here's my call:

```
SomeCollection.insert(Inserts, {'w': 1, 'keepGoing': true}, function(Err, Result) {
    //Callback logic goes here
});
```

Now, I'm **guessing** that:

- In the case that none of the documents get inserted (success): Err is defined and Result is null?
- In the case where all the documents get inserted (failure): Err is null and Result is an array containing all the inserted documents?
- In the case where some of the documents where inserted and some insertions failed (partial success): ?

I find the API (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/collection.html#insert) is downright vague on this issue.

I'll probably have to run some tests and/or look at the source code in order to post an answer later unless someone knows by any chance :)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it this way: Err can only be either null or an instance of a JavaScript Error object. A "partial success" implies that at least one error has occurred and so the method would return an Error, which you would need to handle in your callback. The 'message' property of the Error will usually tell you what you need to know.

In my experience, most documentation for node.js libraries is vague (and, sometimes, non-existent). Reading the source or even simply printing results to the console is pretty much necessary during development.

Check out [this blog post](http://machadogj.com/2013/4/error-handling-in-nodejs.html) for more information on error handling in node.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks for the feedback. Ended up writing a test script which can be found in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote and ran this script:

```
var MongoDB = require('mongodb');

MongoDB.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", {native_parser:true}, function(Err, DB) {
    DB.createCollection('TestCollectionInsertCallback', function(Err, TestCollection) {
        TestCollection.ensureIndex({'UniqueIndex': 1}, {'w': 1, 'unique': true}, function(Err, Index) {
            TestCollection.insert([{'UniqueIndex': 1}, {'UniqueIndex': 2}, {'UniqueIndex': 3}, {'UniqueIndex': 6}], {'w': 1, 'keepGoing': true}, function(Err, Result) {
                console.log('\nSuccessful Inserts Args...');
                console.log('Err:');
                console.log(Err);
                console.log('Result:');
                console.log(Result);
                TestCollection.insert([{'UniqueIndex': 1}, {'UniqueIndex': 2}, {'UniqueIndex': 3}, {'UniqueIndex': 6}], {'w': 1, 'keepGoing': true}, function(Err, Result) {
                    console.log('\nComplete Failure Inserts Args...');
                    console.log('Err:');
                    console.log(Err);
                    console.log('Result:');
                    console.log(Result);
                    TestCollection.insert([{'UniqueIndex': 4}, {'UniqueIndex': 5}, {'UniqueIndex': 6}, {'UniqueIndex': 7}], {'w': 1, 'keepGoing': true}, function(Err, Result) {
                        console.log('\nPartial Success Inserts Args...');
                        console.log('Err:');
                        console.log(Err);
                        console.log('Result:');
                        console.log(Result);
                        TestCollection.find({}).toArray(function(Err, Results) {
                            console.log('\nFinal DB content...');
                            Results.forEach(function(Item, Index, List) {
                                console.log(Item);
                            });
                            DB.dropCollection('TestCollectionInsertCallback', function(Err, Result) {
                                DB.close();
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The output was:

```
Successful Inserts Args...
Err:
null
Result:
[ { UniqueIndex: 1, _id: 5446084afa57911715f18c4e },
  { UniqueIndex: 2, _id: 5446084afa57911715f18c4f },
  { UniqueIndex: 3, _id: 5446084afa57911715f18c50 },
  { UniqueIndex: 6, _id: 5446084afa57911715f18c51 } ]

Complete Failure Inserts Args...
Err:
{ [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: test.TestCollectionInsertCallback.$UniqueIndex_1  dup key: { : 6 }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: test.TestCollectionInsertCallback.$UniqueIndex_1  dup key: { : 6 }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 88,
  ok: 1 }
Result:
null

Partial Success Inserts Args...
Err:
{ [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: test.TestCollectionInsertCallback.$UniqueIndex_1  dup key: { : 6 }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: test.TestCollectionInsertCallback.$UniqueIndex_1  dup key: { : 6 }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 90,
  ok: 1 }
Result:
null

Final DB content...
{ UniqueIndex: 1, _id: 5446084afa57911715f18c4e }
{ UniqueIndex: 2, _id: 5446084afa57911715f18c4f }
{ UniqueIndex: 3, _id: 5446084afa57911715f18c50 }
{ UniqueIndex: 6, _id: 5446084afa57911715f18c51 }
{ UniqueIndex: 4, _id: 5446084afa57911715f18c56 }
{ UniqueIndex: 5, _id: 5446084afa57911715f18c57 }
{ UniqueIndex: 7, _id: 5446084afa57911715f18c59 }
```

So, the answer to the cases provided in the questions are:

- 100% Successful: Err is null, Result contains inserted entries
- 100% failure: Err is an object representing the error, Result is null
- Partial Success: Callback arguments are the same as 100% failure